# How Can i make an object look less subdivided when it is not closer to camera?

Tags: objects, camera, subdivision-surface

I know there is some way to make an object look actually subdivided when it is closer to camera and when the camera goes far from the range the object looks less subdivided in blender?

Can someone help me remember that modifier or technique which works like that?

Comment: Look into Adaptive Subdivision

Comment: Just keep in mind that Adaptive Subdivision only works in Cycles and you need to enable the Experimental Features in the render settings

Comment: You can also control the Decimate or the Subdivision Surface modifer's resolution with a driver, based on the distance between the object and the camera.